# Transformers for SQL to return non entity pojo class

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, transform

hi i am trying to return non entity class of the resulting query using Transformers in hibernate.

My pojo class is

Hibernate code is

```
    public class TestPojo {

    private String id=null;
    private String companyname=null;
    private String fullname=null;
    private String empid=null;
    private String dateallocated=null;
    public TestPojo() {

    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCompanyname() {
        return companyname;
    }
    public void setCompanyname(String companyname) {
        this.companyname = companyname;
    }
    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }
    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
    public String getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    public void setEmpid(String empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
    public String getDateallocated() {
        return dateallocated;
    }
    public void setDateallocated(String dateallocated) {
        this.dateallocated = dateallocated;
    }




        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select t.id as id,t.companyname      as           companyname,e.fullname as fullname,e.empid as empid,ca.dateallocated as    dateallocated from   bw_tempclientdetails t,  bw_employee_details e, bw_clientallocation   ca   where  e.empid=ca.empid and  ca.companyname=t.companyname");

         query.addScalar("id");    
         query.addScalar("companyname");
         query.addScalar("fullname");
         query.addScalar("empid");
         query.addScalar("dateallocated");


query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TestPojo.class));
List<TestPojo> list=query.list();
```

But when i run my application i get this error.
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of org.bluewhale.model.TestPojo.id

enter code here

Comment: Problem solved                                 query.addScalar("id",Hibernate.STRING);
    query.addScalar("companyname",Hibernate.STRING);
    query.addScalar("fullname",Hibernate.STRING);
    query.addScalar("empid",Hibernate.STRING);
    query.addScalar("dateallocated",Hibernate.STRING);
    query.addScalar("status",Hibernate.STRING);


query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllocatedClients.class));
    list=query.list();

cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your comments:-

```
query.addScalar("id",Hibernate.STRING);
query.addScalar("companyname",Hibernate.STRING); 
query.addScalar("fullname",Hibernate.STRING); 
query.addScalar("empid",Hibernate.STRING); 
query.addScalar("dateallocated",Hibernate.STRING);
query.addScalar("status",Hibernate.STRING); 
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TestPojo.class)); 
list=query.list();
```

**Explanation** :

To explain in general Hibernate chooses the most suitable the way in which the data can be represented. So I assume that the `IDs` are stored in number format. Hence Hibernate considers them as `Long`. The `aliasToBean` method calls the default constructor to make the `TestPojo` object. It then searches for the setter methods for its *self deduced* types. In this case probably it searches for the method with signature

```
  public void setId(Long id)
```

this call goes to the overloaded method `public void setId(String id)`

Since `Long` is not `String` you get a `IllegalArgumentException`.

What you did in the solution is explicitly define the values to be taken as type `String` hence now the setter method used by Hibernate becomes `public void setId(String id)` therefore solving your problem.

Please Note:- If you are to use `addScalar()` you need to use it for all the data members needed.